# Flutter: How to Queue multiple streams

Tags: flutter, dart

I have stream like the below-mentioned code, here want to merge streams and wanted to call it one by one whenever it required.

```
main() {
  Stream<String> stream = new Stream.fromFuture(getData());

  stream.listen((data) {
    print("DataReceived: "+data);
  }, onDone: () {
    print("Task Done");
  });
  
}

Future<String> getData() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)); //Mock delay 
  print("Fetched Data");
  return "This a test data";
}
```

`onDone` will be called after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

For it, `StreamQueue` can be used to combine multiple streams

**Add Dependency:**

```
async: ^2.4.1
```

**Use StreamQueue:**

```
void main() async {
  Stream<String> stream1 = new Stream.fromFuture(getData(2));
  Stream<String> stream2 = new Stream.fromFuture(getData(4));
  Stream<String> stream3 = new Stream.fromFuture(getData(6));
  var streams = StreamGroup.merge([stream1, stream2, stream3]);

  var data = StreamQueue(streams);
  var first = await data.next;
  print(first);
  var second = await data.next;
  print(second);
  var third = await data.next;
  print(third);
  var third1 = await data.next;
  print(third1);
}

Future<String> getData(int duration) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: duration)); //Mock delay
  return "This a test data for duration $duration";
}
```

**Output:**

```
I/flutter ( 7950): This a test data for duration 2
I/flutter ( 7950): This a test data for duration 4
I/flutter ( 7950): This a test data for duration 6
```

> `data.next` will provide you the first stream in Queue which is in our
> case is stream1, here we can take the future value and use. `stream.next` gives next stream in the queue if nothing exists in queue & stream.next is performed then it will throw an exception.